# How to erase all contacts from an Android phone?

Tags: contacts, google-contacts

How to erase all contacts from an Android phone?
There are about 3200 contacts.

### The full story

I don't manage my contacts with Google Contacts, but with another tool that can export to the VCF format.

The first time I imported my VCF file into Google Contacts, my Android phone synced and got all contacts, perfect.

After a while, having new contacts, I exported to VCF again, and imported again to Google Calendar. All contacts got duplicated on the phone.

I removed all contacts using Google Contacts web interface in Gmail, and re-imported, but contacts get duplicated every time.

I just want to start from scratch, remove all contacts, and import from my new VCF file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work for you?
contacts -> menu -> delete -> select all -> delete

If not there are apps "Delete Contacts" in the market you could try.

Comment: In the contacts app (came by default on my HTC Magic Android 1.5), the menu only contains: Search, New contact, Display group, Edit sync groups, import contacts. No "delete" option :-( Now I will look for the apps you mention.

Comment: The "delete contacts" application from "United Mobile Apps Pvt Ltd" works as advertised :-) It takes quite a long time, so the "close or wait" dialog appears, but just wait for a dozen minutes and a message appears when all of the contacts are gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I cant find that option in my Nexus 7. It seems they have removed this in Jellybean or Kitkat. This is what i do.

> Settings>Apps>All> Contacts> Clear data, clear cache
>
> Settings>Apps>All> Contacts Storage > Clear data, clear cache

This will clear all the database of the People app.

Comment: Beware that clearing the DATA of "Contacts Storage" will reset the CALL LOG!!! Make a backup (i recommend this great app! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore)

Answer (score -2):

[image: screenshot]

that is very easy. you should go setting>app>all>contact and remove data

Comment: This answer already says so: [How to erase all contacts from an Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/65432) Is there a reason you posted a duplicate?

Comment: @Firelord: It is nice to have a screenshot, I would say.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I'd say there is no point in adding redundancy unless you  add something more useful. How is that screenshot (without any editing (the clues, hints)) anymore useful then the one line steps in the other answer, I fail to see here.  That screenshot fits as a comment to an existing answer.

Comment: By image ppls have to understand more clearly. That gives more accuracy

Comment: @ShashankPriyadarshi It depends upon for what category of users you're posting your answer. You can argue that a screenshot provides familiarity in the answer, but there would also be users who would still  find it hard to follow the answer unless specific hints/marks in the screenshot(s) is/are provided. Anyway, I'll leave this answer for the rest of the users to decide. Please keep up the good work of answering though.